# Converting integer date value to Datetime in Python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe with tickers, returns, and dates in the format, for example, of "20200101". I'm trying to convert these values to Datetime values. However, when I attempt the following:

```
fin_data['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(fin_data['DATE'])
```

The output is recognizing the date I have (which I'd like to be in YYYY-MM-DD format) as nanoseconds, so the output is something like this:

```
1970-01-01 00:00:00.020200101
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Desired output is `2020-01-01`, right?

Comment: Why is it an integer in the first place? If you're reading from a CSV for example, you can specify, `pd.read_csv(parse_dates=['DATE'])`.

Answer (score 1):

Specify the format:

```
fin_data = pd.DataFrame({'DATE': [20200101]})

pd.to_datetime(fin_data['DATE'], format='%Y%d%m')
```

Output:

```
0   2020-01-01
Name: DATE, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```